# Flutter TabBarView expands children

Tags: flutter

In the following code `TabBarView` expands children `LinearProgressIndicator` , How can I fix it ?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              LinearProgressIndicator(),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some workaround like this may suit your case, in your `TabView`

```
TabBarView(
        children: [
          Column(children: [ Container(child: LinearProgressIndicator())]),
          Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
          Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
        ],
),
```

Explanation: Consider this workaround

```
body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
```

I am just try to understand what I understand from the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBarView/children.html).
Each `tab` accepts one widget. So it just expands through out it.
As you can see here,

[image]

First `Container` widget is considered to be that one widget per tab. (Now this Container has full width and height).

So, if I add `Column` (also expands to full height and width) with it and make `LinearProgressIndicator` as child of another `Container`, it will not expands through all its height, as we didn't define it.

Did you see? `LinearProgressIndicator` just expanded to its parent `Container` of fixed height and we can't see the yellow color. That's what happened in your question. `LinearProgressIndicator` just expanded as `TabBarView` accepts one widget per `Tab`

> Why ConstrainedBox, SizedBox or Container with double.infinite height
> instead of Column not works?

See this [TabBarView Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBarView/TabBarView.html), says that,

> Creates a page view with one child per tab.

So if we see [PageView Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html), it says

> Each child of a page view is forced to be the same size as the
> viewport.

So, even though we use `SizedBox` and other widgets with specific `height`, the parent (PageView) forces to expand to viewport's dimension.

If we see [LinearProgressIndicator Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator-class.html), it says,

```
The minimum height of the indicator can be specified using minHeight. The indicator can be made taller by wrapping the widget with a SizedBox.
```

So without `Column`, `LinearProgressIndicator` is taller to its full height since we used `SizedBox`

Hope that works!

Comment: It works, but I am looking for a cleaner approach, Can you please tell me how TabBarView expands its children?

Comment: Im curious why SizedBox didn't work when I checked it

Comment: @WebMaster I guess the question for TabBarView is what about the remaining space ? "Im as TabBarView took all the place and you want me to take only that much ?"

Comment: Just updated the answer with what I understand. It may help you!

Comment: @ShriHari Why `ConstrainedBox`, `SizedBox` or `Container` with `double.infinite` height instead of `Column` not works?

Comment: Updated the answer. Just my views on that. Have a look